# MonoDevelop's Images directory does not seen on XCode(IB)

Tags: xamarin.ios

In my project files marshalling shown below ,Mono Develop doesn't show Images directory(group) in XCode and they are not seen on xib interfaces,also crashes on runtime. But when I put images under Project's root directory works fine!

Fine! But seeing dozens of images on root directory make things confusing.

Here goes details;

- My images built actions are content.
- I have tried adding them to Xcode by creating a group named Images then this time all images copied to Mono Develop's root again.

Am I missing something?

Project

--Images

---- FaceOff.Png

---- icons

---------CandyButton32x.png

Comment: Put the images in Resources folder

Comment: All of their Build action turned to Resource. This time XCode Project's root directory full of images.

Comment: I had the same problem, just setting the Build Action showed the images in Xcode but they weren't loading at runtime

Comment: Xamarin says Build Action must be Content for images. But I did not found anything about location.

Comment: I'm on trial. I also can't use 3rd party project's such as QuartzCore.framework. I would like to combine my .Net development library and Xamarin's mobile framework it would be great but I've http://stackoverflow.com/q/14734102/413032 problem also. Anyway this is not a chat area...

Comment: The Resources folder is more of an organizational folder allowing users to not clutter their C# Project's toplevel folder with tons of images. In order for .xib files to find images, they *must* be in the toplevel Xcode directory or it won't find the images at runtime.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are experiencing a limitation of the XCode integration with MonoDevelop.

Images only show up in XCode if they are in the root directory of your project.  To combat this, there are two ways you can setup your image folders for MonoTouch projects:

- Use build action `Content`, put your images anywhere, but they will only show up in XCode if they are in the root of the project
- Use the build action `BundleResource` and put all your images in the `Resources` folder, this is the same as putting your images in the root of the project, but you get to package them nicely in a subfolder

I have not experimented with `BundleResource` and XCode to see if subfolders work via that method or not.

This is from my experience, someone from Xamarin, feel free to chime in.

Comment: Jonathan is correct. FWIW, the Resources folder automatically sets the BuildAction of files to "BundleResource" (which is the correct BuildAction to use). "BundleResource" is just like "Content" (which we are deprecating), but allows you to set a LogicalName to change its install location.

Answer (score 2):

Further to Jonathan's great answer, I have a nice organised setup for my images using BundleResource and the Resources Folder.

- On the filesystem I have all my images in a nice directory structure, for example: **img/common/title.png**.
- I then add all the image files (not directories) into the iOS project **Resources** folder, using the **'Add Files'** option and selecting **BundleResource** for the files I select.
- When given the copy, move or link option, because my files are outside the target directory, I select the **'Add a link to the file'** option.

This procedure allows me to:

- Happily keep all my images in an organised directory structure on the file system
- Have access to them in XCode Interface Builder
- Access them as root when in code, such as Image.FromFile("title.png")
- Easily update them in the filesystem and have them automatically change in Xamarin Studio