# QuartzCore.framework for Mono Develop

Tags: xamarin.ios, monodevelop, quartz-core

I'm fine with Mono Develop's native-supported iOS libraries. 
But when I need such as a 3rd party library I get stuck.

QuartzCore is a successful library,but written in Objective-C. 
I know there is binding type project supported by xamarin.
http://docs.xamarin.com/ios/Guides/Advanced_Topics/Binding_Objective-C_Libraries

Maybe for a small project has .a extension could be easy to bind. I wonder do I need to try to bind QuartzCore.framework to Mono Develop or Does it take much effort then coding in XCode by Objective C.

Does anyone tried this binding? There are some other projects already bound such as CorePlot https://github.com/mono/monotouch-bindings/tree/master/CorePlot.

I can't decide what I need to do. Will it be easy or bring me much job?

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm pretty sure that QuartzCore is already bound in MonoTouch. I think QuartzCore is part of CoreAnimation, which may be why you didn't see it.

Comment: More precisely, what should one do to use it in monotouch?

Comment: You don't need to do anything, it is already bound in MonoTouch.dll.